# Remove all rows containing a piece of a string in multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a very large dataframe with many columns. I want to check all the columns and remove any row containing any instance of the string 'MU', and there are some columns that have 'MU#1' or 'MU#2', and they will sometimes switch places (like 'MU#1 would be in column 1 at index 0 and 'MU#2' will be in column 1 at index 1). Initially, I tried removing them with this but it becomes far too cumbersome if I try to do this for both strings above:

```
df_slice = df[(df.phase_2 != 'MU#1') & (df.phase_3 != 'MU#1') & (df.phase_1 != 'MU#1') & (df.phase_4 != 'MU#1') ]
```

This may work, but I have to repeat this slice a few times with other dataframes and I imagine there is a much simpler route. I also have more columns than what is shown above, but that is just a snippet.
Simply put, all columns need to be checked for 'MU' and the rows with 'MU' need to be removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try `.str.contains()` and apply to the dataframe. This avoids hardcoding the columns in just in case

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: (~x.str.contains('MU', case=True, regex=True)))].dropna()
```

or

```
df[~df.stack().str.contains('MU').any(level=0)]
```

**How it work**s

Option 1

when used in `df.apply()`, `x.str.contains`, #is a wild card for any column in the datframe that contains

`x.str.contains('MU', case=True, regex=True)` is a wild card for any column in the datframe that contains 'MU', case sensitive and regular expression implied

`~` Reverses, hence you end up with rows that do not have MU

Resulting dataframe returns `NaN` where the condition is not met. `.dropna()` hence eliminates the rows with `NaN`

Option 2

```
df.stack()# Stacks the dataframe
df.stack().str.contains('MU')#boolean selects rows with the string 'MU'
df.stack().str.contains('MU').any(level=0)# Selects the index
~df.stack().str.contains('MU').any(level=0)# Reverses the selection taking only those without string 'MU'
```

Answer (score 1):

What we do with `all`

```
df = df[df[['phase_1','phase_2','phase_3','phase_4']].ne('MU#1').all(1)]
```

Update

```
df = df[(~df[['phase_1','phase_2','phase_3','phase_4']].isin(['MU#1','MU#2'])).all(1)]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any to remove more than just that 1 string in the same line? For example, I now want to remove rows that contain 'MU#1' or 'SIGMA' or 'MU#2'

Comment: @Austin check the update ~ also if this work , would you like accept it ?> check mark at the left

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with me.

```
df[~df.stack().str.contains('Any String').any(level=0)]
```

Even when searching specific string in the dataframe

```
df[df.stack().str.contains('Any String').any(level=0)]
```

Thanks.